# osrf/ros docker images don't contain Gazebo packages

Tags: ros, gazebo, docker

I am trying to move my local development environment to a container.

I had no problems setting up the container using the docker images provided by https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/tree/master

However, the problem is that some of the images do not have the Gazebo packages that are present on my local ROS installation (Humble). Namely these packages inside /opt/ros/humble/share/:

[image]

I have tried 3 different images:

- osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full-jammy: No Gazebo packages
- osrf/ros:foxy-desktop-full-focal: No Gazebo packages
- osrf/ros:noetic-desktop-full-focal: Yes Gazebo packages

Does anyone know why some images have the gazebo packages installed and some don't?

Additionally, I really want to stick with Humble as it is the ROS distro I was using on my local machine. How do I install the Gazebo packages manually?

Note: Installing Gazebo is not the problem. I have successfully made a custom Dockerfile that takes from osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full-jammy and installs Gazebo separately and I was able to start Gazebo. However, installing it separately does not provide the ROS packages I need. Especially the gazebo_ros and gazebo_plugins packages.

Answer (score 0):

The variants for ROS 2 are defined in [REP 2001](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2001.html#humble-hawksbill-may-2022-may-2027)

```
- desktop_full:
    extends:  [desktop]
    packages: [perception, simulation, ros_ign_gazebo_demos]
```

I think that the problem that you're running into is that the name for Gazebo was Ignition for a period, where the package names were slightly different.

```
$ rocker osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full apt-cache search ign | grep ros
FROM osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full
ros-humble-ignition-cmake2-vendor - This package provides the Ignition CMake 2.x library.
ros-humble-ignition-math6-vendor - This package provides the Ignition Math 6.x library.
ros-humble-laser-filters - Assorted filters designed to operate on 2D planar laser scanners, which use the sensor_msgs/LaserScan type.
ros-humble-resource-retriever - This package retrieves data from url-format files such as http://, ftp://, package:// file://, etc., and loads the data into memory.
ros-humble-ros-ign-bridge - Shim package to redirect to ros_gz_bridge.
ros-humble-ros-ign-gazebo - Shim package to redirect to ros_gz_sim.
ros-humble-ros-ign-gazebo-demos - Shim package to redirect to ros_gz_sim_demos.
ros-humble-ros-ign-image - Shim package to redirect to ros_gz_image.
ros-humble-ros-ign-interfaces - Shim package to redirect to ros_gz_interfaces.
```

We returned to using the Gazebo name fully in 2022:

https://community.gazebosim.org/t/a-new-era-for-gazebo/1356

There's now Gazebo Classic and Gazebo Sim (or gz)